# How to fix 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)' in order_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, argument-error

My app was working perfectly an hour ago, then I added two columns, `:pick_up` and `:send` to the 'orders' table, and after that I got this error

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I don't see why that should be causing this error though.

Here is orders_controller.rb:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]

  def index
    @orders = Order.all? 
  end

  def new
    @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
    @random_no = rand(5)
    @random_image = @images[@random_no]

    if @cart.product_items.empty?
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Cart is Empty'
      return

    end
    @order = Order.new
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
      charge
      if @result.success?
        @order.add_product_items_from_cart(@cart)
      Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil
      OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver 
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thank You for Your Order'
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Please Check Your Cart'
        redirect_to root_url, alert: @result.message
        @order.destroy
      end
    else
      @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
      render :new
    end
  end


  def show

  end


  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order deleted'
  end

  private

  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :country, :pick_up, :send)
  end

  def charge
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        amount: @cart.total_price_usd,
        payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce] )
  end

end
```

This is _form.html.erb for the orders:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= render 'msg' %>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h3>Please Enter Your Details</h3>
    </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <%= f.label :email%>
      <%= f.email_field :email, size: 40, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <%= f.label :address %>
      <%= f.text_area :address, cols: 40, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <%= f.label :city %>
      <%= f.text_field :city, size: 40, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%= f.label :country %>
      <%= f.country_select :country, { priority_countries: [ "IS", "US", "DE", "ES", "PT" ]}, { class: "form-control" }%>
    </div>


  </div>  


  <div class="form-group">

    <div id="payment-form"></div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
      <br>
      <%= f.submit 'Place Order', class: 'buttons' %>

    </div>
  </div>  

  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the order part of schema.rb:

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.text     "address"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "country"
  t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  t.boolean  "shipped",    default: false
  t.string   "pick_up"
  t.string   "send"
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend setting your editor to use spaces for indentation, rather than tabs. It's idiomatic in the Ruby community and will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fear `send` is not a lucky name for an identifier because the `send` method.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: Of course, that is probably it, I´ll check it out, thanks